# XHR Upload progress event has stopped firing

Tags: javascript, upload

I have a file upload with progress based on XHR feedback that has been working for many years but lately, the upload progress event has stopped firing. We have not made any changes, so I thought there was a behaviour change by the browser. I have tried uploading form-data as multipart, JSON, and a normal blob as octet-stream but no success. Download progress is working splendidly.

Below is the bare minimum to test uploading a 25mb blob. The blob is sent and well received, but progress is not firing.

```
const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(25 * 1024 * 1024)]); // any Blob, including a File
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT", "/api/files", true);
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => console.log(evt), false)
xhr.send(blob);
```

Is there something I am missing? Is it something that must be sent due to some change in standards?

Comment: I used your code sample as is and I can see the progress events logged in the Chrome console. I used Chrome v120.0.6099.129 with a simple local Express.js server.